# Issues with Pointing Godaddy domain to MY Azure Linux VM

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, azure, dns, ubuntu-12.04

What I have done so far:
This is my first server I have set up from scratch. Basically the issue is that i have build an vm on my azure cloud, set up wordpress, mysql database, php all that good stuff, I can even see my site when i look up the ip address.

In my godaddy Account I have set the A record to point to my domain and the CNAME to point to the azure app domain blahblah.azurecloud.net or something like that.

The ISSUE: 
When I go to the url http://www.weirdwildmedia.com/ my wordpress template comes up no problem, BUT if i click on a link you will see

```
    http://168.63.15.56/?page_id=2
```

Can anyone shed some light on this for me as its so annoying to have it almost set up and this small thing holding me back from designing the site.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you installed and configured Wordpress to use `http://168.63.15.56/`

Go into your `wp_options` table in your database. First, locate:

```
site_url
```

Then adjust that to

http://www.weirdwildmedia.com/

Next, locate:

```
home_url
```

Then adjust that to:

http://www.weirdwildmedia.com/

Resolved.

Comment: Hahaha I was thinking that just now.. jesus.. thanks a lot dude il give it a try now.